# PHP: for loop showing same result twice instead of the two distinct results?

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have a SELECT query in MySQL, that I've tested in phpMyAdmin and it shows two records, where the same user (Number 1), has two roles (*noAutorizado* and *admin*):

Now, I've tried to show that in a list using a for loop, and it shows the first result twice instead the two results. 
So instead of showing *noAutorizado* and *admin*, it shows *noAutorizado* and *noAutorizado*.

What's wrong with the loop?

```
$conectar2 = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE);
$buscarRoles = "SELECT userID, nombreRol
          FROM rolesUsuarios
          WHERE userID='$uid'
          ";
$roles = mysqli_query($conectar2,$buscarRoles);     

    if($roles){
        $rol = mysqli_fetch_array($roles);
        $cantRegistros = mysqli_num_rows($roles);
        for ($i=0; $i < $cantRegistros; $i++) { 
            echo $rol['nombreRol'].'<br>';
        }
    } else ...
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` fetches one role

Comment: while($rol = mysqli_fetch_array($roles)) {  echo $rol['nombreRol'].'<br>'; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the array represents a single row in the returned result set. You need to execute the [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) function again to get the next record. Example:

```
 while($rol = mysqli_fetch_array($roles)) { echo $rol['nombreRol'].'<br>'; }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to fetch the results in a loop

```
$conectar2 = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DATABASE);
$buscarRoles = "SELECT userID, nombreRol
          FROM rolesUsuarios
          WHERE userID='$uid'";
$roles = mysqli_query($conectar2,$buscarRoles);     

if($roles){
    while( $rows=mysqli_fetch_object($roles) ){
        echo $rows->nombreRol.'<br>';
    }   
}
```